# How to improve my API performance which fetches 30 days data from db

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-restcontroller

I'm using spring boot to implement my REST service. It needs to fetch data from db having 30 days worth of data in it and provide response. With the current Implementation I have it is taking 35 secs to populate the data. I'm looking for better approach which optimizes the response time.

**Controller.java**

```
@RestController
@Slf4j
@RequestMapping("/api/inbound-visibility")
public class IvController {

      @Autowired
      DataService dataService;
    
      @GetMapping(value = "/data")
      public ResponseEntity<GraphResponse> getData(){
        log.info("Getting Data");
        return new ResponseEntity<>(dataService.getData(), HttpStatus.OK);
      }
}
```

```
Repo.java
```

```
 public interface GraphRepository extends
          JpaRepository<IvOrdeCube,String> {
  @Query(value = "select CAL_DT as CALDATE,
      sum (ORDER_QTY) as palletqty,
      sum (PAL_QTY) as orderqty 
      from [IV_ORDER_CUBE] 
      where SOURCE_SYSTEM = 'RAW' group by CAL_DT order by CAL_DT 
      ASC",nativeQuery = true)
      List<ForecastedOrder> getForecastedData();
  }
```

```
ServiceImpl.java
```

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class ServiceImpl implements DataService{

    @Autowired
    Repo repository;

  private DataResponse dataResponseBuilder(){
    DataResponse response = new DataResponse();
    response.setPallets(foreCasteResponseBuilder());
    return response;
  }

private PalletsForeCast foreCasteResponseBuilder(){
    List<ForecastOrder> palletOrders = new ArrayList<>();
    PalletsForeCast palletsForeCast = new PalletsForeCast();
    log.info("Sizes Of Orders: {} {} {}", getForeCastedOrderForRequest().size(), getFirmOrderForRequest().size(), getManualOrderForRequest().size());
    for(int index = 0; index < getForeCastedOrderForRequest().size(); index ++){
      log.info("Size of orders: {} {} {} {} {} {}", getForeCastedOrderForRequest().size(), getFirmOrderForRequest().size(), getManualOrderForRequest().size(),
          getForeCastedOrderForRequest().get(index).getCalDate(),
          getForeCastedOrderForRequest().get(index).getPalletOrderQty(),
          getForeCastedOrderForRequest().get(index).getUnitOrderQty());
      ForecastOrder forecastOrder = new ForecastOrder();
      Orders orders = new Orders();
      forecastOrder.setDate(getForeCastedOrderForRequest().get(index).getCalDate());
      orders.setForecastedOrders(getForeCastedOrderForRequest().get(index).getPalletOrderQty());
      forecastOrder.setForecastedOrders(orders);
      palletOrders.add(forecastOrder);
      palletsForeCast.setForecast(palletOrders);
    }
    return palletsForeCast;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

add Indexes for given WHERE statements.

SOURCE_SYSTEM, CAL_DT

Answer (score 0):

In addition to configuring indexes in the database, as mentioned by Kutay Zorlu in his answer, you could consider adding a pagination feature to your REST endpoint.